# Can HP Vertica be used as an C# Entity Framework provider?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6, vertica

I have been trying to add as I do with MS SQL Server but its never appears in the list as a type to select from

Comment: Not unless there's a provider library available for EF.

Comment: Anyone know if there is one?  I haven't had much searching so I'm thinking no....

Answer (score 0):

That's not the answer you expect, and you probably already read about it, but even if there's a way to use Vertica with a C# Entity provider, you probably don't want to go down this way.

We tried to achieve the same thing in Java, using hibernate to store objects in Vertica. This was for the sake of convenience : storing all of our data in a single place seemed like a good idea. We created a couple of tables with a few thousand lines max, storing objects loaded by Hibernate. The content of the tables was updated several times per hour.

**It quickly brought Vertica on its knees**. The update process was filling the Vertica  Write Optimized Store (WOS), causing a [WOS overflow](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#4983.htm). Reading performance was bad, since all columns of each table were retrieved (given the column oriented structure of Vertica tables, this would be equivalent to creating a table for each column in a row oriented database, and then joining all these tables to retrieve a single row). We ended up storing hibernate objects in a MySQL database, in order to only keep in Vertica the large volume of data which was intended to be analyzed/aggregated.

In short, before looking for a Vertica C# Entity provider, just make sure you do know exactly how your provider will be used, the structure and complexity of your entities, and how Vertica will handle it.

Good luck :)